# In SAQL, what's the equivalent of the SQL keyword "HAVING"?

Tags: saql

The SQL keyword HAVING is used like a WHERE clause except that HAVING works on aggregated groups. Is there a way to do this in SAQL?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

in Salesforce Object Query Language (SOQL) the HAVING word is documented as https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm

Answer (score 0):

In SAQL, the FILTER BY seems to pull double duty and also functions  as the HAVING keyword (SAQL is for Einstein Analytics, now called Tableau CRM).

Here's a sample example where you can filter out the groups with count less than 16:

"query": "q = load "DTCOwRf";\nq = group q by 'Billing_Country';\nq = foreach q generate 'Billing_Country' as 'Billing_Country', count() as 'count';\nq = filter q by 'count' <= 50;\nq=filter q by 'count' > 16;\nq = order q by 'count' desc;\nq = limit q 2000;",

Happy N.Y. to all.